# How do I output html data and text to a page after the page has loaded. Not before

Tags: html, jsp, jdbc, jakarta-ee

Hey guys.  Basically I need to dump and incredible amount of tables and text to a web page.  I'm pulling the information from a database.  All the querying is done and the page loads with all the tables in place.  I would like to instantly load the page and then start pulling the information down if that's possible.  Or possibly lazy load the tables.  Thanks for any help.

I'm putting all the information to the page via a string builder.

Thanks for the help

Comment: This sounds like a textbook job for AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use any Ajax on your site?  That would probably be the easiest way to 'lazily' load certain aspects of your page after it has been rendered.  [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a popular JavaScript library that can help you with some AJAX interactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data into a div that was display:none then display it back using some button with display:block. Where the data is already formatted as what you like. Use may JQuery so you can load it with animation or use its ajax.